# Protobuf does not generate appropriate declarations

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers

[UPDATE]
It seems that protobuf_generate_cpp uses absolute paths.
Invoking protobuf compiler manually specifying relative path seems to generate valid sources.

Manual:

> /usr/bin/protoc --cpp_out /home/pp/Projects/SmartHomeManagement/shm-iw/build shmiw/metadata/metadata.proto

produces: (metadata.pb.h)

> ::DescriptorTable descriptor_table_shmiw_2fmetadata_2fmetadata_2eproto;

Name contains subdirectories

Whereas when compiling by protobuf_generate_cpp from cmake, it invokes protobuf compiler with command:

> /usr/bin/protoc --cpp_out /home/pp/Projects/SmartHomeManagement/shm-iw/build -I /home/pp/Projects/SmartHomeManagement/shm-iw/shmiw/metadata /home/pp/Projects/SmartHomeManagement/shm-iw/shmiw/metadata/metadata.proto

which produces "invalid" names that can't be used later on by other packages: (metadata.pb.h)

> ::DescriptorTable descriptor_table_metadata_2eproto;

I've got some problem with protobuf. I've got 3 proto files. The first one is a proto file that contains an option that all other proto files use. All proto files are organized in the same structure, and each of them belongs to a separate package. I want to generate all .h and .cc files and then put them into one single static library.
Project structure is as follows:

```
/root-dir
-CMakeLists.txt (1)
-shm-iw/
  - CMakeLists.txt (2)
  - bci
    - CMakeLists.txt (3)
    - bci.proto
  - icon
    - CMakeLists.txt (4)
    - icon.proto
  - metadata
    - CMakeLists.txt (5)
    - metadata.proto
```

Root CMakeLists.txt (1)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

project(shm-iw CXX)

set(SHM-IW_VERSION 0.1)

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)

include_directories(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR})
set (Protobuf_IMPORT_DIRS ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR} )

add_subdirectory(shm-iw)
```

shm-iw CMakeLists.txt (2)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)

add_subdirectory(metadata)
add_subdirectory(bci)
add_subdirectory(icon)
```

bci CMakeLists.txt (3)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)


protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS
  bci.proto
)

add_library(bci_objlib OBJECT
  ${PROTO_SRCS}
  ${PROTO_HDRS}
)
target_link_libraries(bci_objlib metadata_objlib)

add_dependencies(bci_objlib metadata_objlib)
```

bci.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

/* Board Control Interface */

import "shmiw/metadata/metadata.proto"; //Note the path to metadata.proto 

package shm.iw.bci;

enum IndicatorType {
  Status = 0;
  Warning = 1;
  Maintenance = 2;
  Fault = 3;
}
enum IndicatorState {
  SteadyOff = 0;
  SteadyOn = 1;
  Blink = 2;
};


message GetVisualIndicationReq
{
  option (shm.iw.metadata.MESSAGE_NUMBER) = 0x1000101;
  IndicatorType indicator = 1;
}

message GetVisualIndicationCfm
{
  option (shm.iw.metadata.MESSAGE_NUMBER) = 0x1000102;

  IndicatorType indicator = 1;
  IndicatorState state = 2;
}
```

metadata CMakeLists.txt (5)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12)


protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS
  metadata.proto
)

add_library(metadata_objlib OBJECT
  ${PROTO_SRCS}
  ${PROTO_HDRS}
)
```

metadata.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";

import "google/protobuf/descriptor.proto";

package shm.iw.metadata;

extend google.protobuf.MessageOptions {
  uint32 MESSAGE_NUMBER = 50001;
}
```

I skipped icon directory as it's almost the same as bci directory, they just have different messages but it's not relevant now.

When I'm compiling I'm getting an error

> shm-iw/build/shm-iw/bci/bci.pb.cc:183:6: error: ‘::descriptor_table_shm_2diw_2fmetadata_2fmetadata_2eproto’ has not been declared
> 183 |   &::descriptor_table_shmiw_2fmetadata_2fmetadata_2eproto,
> |      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Looking at the metadata.pb.h we've got something like this:

> extern const ::PROTOBUF_NAMESPACE_ID::internal::DescriptorTable descriptor_table_metadata_2eproto;

Let's compare the name of the missing declaration and the declaration generated in metadata.pb.h

> metadata.pb.h: descriptor_table_metadata_2eproto

> bci.pb.c:  descriptor_table_shmiw_2fmetadata_2fmetadata_2eproto

They look very similar to each other, but the second one has a few additional words: shm, iw, metadata, which seem to correspond to import path defined in bci.proto

> import "shmiw/metadata/metadata.proto";

What's the reason why it happens? Why does the protobuf compiler not generate the metadata's "decriptor_tabele*" accordingly to the package which is defined in metadata.proto?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Protoc handling of path names is pretty confusing, but here are the basics:

- Input file names are separated to **include dir** and **relative path**.
- **Relative path** determines the name of the symbols that go into generated files.
- **Include dir** must match a directory given with `-I`.
- If no `-I` arguments are given, there is always an implicit `-I .`

Based on this, we can figure out why it works the way it works for you:

**Case 1: relative path**

```
/usr/bin/protoc
  --cpp_out /home/pp/Projects/SmartHomeManagement/shm-iw/build
  shmiw/metadata/metadata.proto
```

No `-I` is given, so `-I .` is assumed. The relative path is `shmiw/metadata/metadata.proto`, giving the symbol name of `descriptor_table_shmiw_2fmetadata_2fmetadata_2eproto`. The `2f` and `2e` stand for `/` and `.` which are not valid in symbol names.

**Case 2: absolute path**

```
/usr/bin/protoc
   --cpp_out /home/pp/Projects/SmartHomeManagement/shm-iw/build
   -I /home/pp/Projects/SmartHomeManagement/shm-iw/shmiw/metadata 
   /home/pp/Projects/SmartHomeManagement/shm-iw/shmiw/metadata/metadata.proto
```

Now the path relative to `-I` directory is just `metadata.proto`. Thus you get `descriptor_table_metadata_2eproto` as the symbol name.

**Case 3: absolute path, but same symbol name as case 1**

```
/usr/bin/protoc
   --cpp_out /home/pp/Projects/SmartHomeManagement/shm-iw/build
   -I /home/pp/Projects/SmartHomeManagement/shm-iw
   /home/pp/Projects/SmartHomeManagement/shm-iw/shmiw/metadata/metadata.proto
```

After this simple change to `-I` directory, it will give the same symbol name as in case 1.